# Does this movement invalidate salah?

Tags: salat, women, hijab, fatwa, fatwa-explanation

When I was raising my hands before ruku, I quickly fixed my sleeve because I was scared that my arms might show. Does this invalidate my prayer? I know that excessive or unnecessary movements could possibly invalidate salah, but I’m not sure about what to do in this case.

Comment: look up on google what invalidates salah, and if you think your salah is invalidated then just repeat it. Jazak Allah brother

Comment: I'm a sister but thanks I did google it, I often read 'excessive and unnecessary movements' but I don’t know if this counts

Comment: Im pretty sure this doesn’t nullify your salat because it’s not unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

To answer these religious questions, it is necessary to know the esteemed source of your imitation. But I answer in general and based on the opinion of Imami jurists. You moved your hands when you finished reading the surahs of praise and monotheism. And you were going to bow. Therefore, in general, you did not invalidate the prayer.
Because it is wrong to move and get out of the stillness of prayer while reciting the surahs of praise and monotheism.
But it is better not to repeat this behavior next time.

https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa5463

https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa48022